# Add a Text overlay to this slideshow from a <p> tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, text, pagination, overlay, slideshow

I have this slideshow and I want each image to have a headline and description overlay the image and fade in and out with the images with it...

i THINK i HAVE TO COPY THE SOL VARIABLE ON EACH INSTANCE ITS USED

```
//sol = document.getElementById('slidy').getElementsByTagName('img')
//var sho = document.getElementById('slidya').getElementsByTagName('a');
```

BUT i WAS TRYING TO SEE IF THERE IS A WAY TO CALL BOTH THE:'a' and 'p' tags together without adding a whole mess of code

for instance here would be what I want the HTML to look like

```
<div id="slidy" class="slidepart fl">
                <img width="100%" src="/img/1.jpg">
                <p>Here is some text...</p>
                <img width="100%" src="/img/2.jpg">
                <p>Here is somemore text...</p>
                <img width="100%" src="/img/3.jpg">
                <p>even more text...</p>
                <img width="100%" src="/img/4.jpg">
                <p>one more time with some text...</p>
                <img width="100%" src="/img/5.jpg">
                <p>Finally, some text...</p>
                   <div class="sl_paginationpart">
```

> > > > > > > > > BELOW IS WHAT I HAVE NOW >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

HTML:

```
<div class="slideContainer">
   <div class="slides">
      <div class="contents" style="width:100%;  margin:0px auto; overflow:hidden;">
         <div id="slidy" class="slidepart fl">
            <img width="100%" src="/img/1.jpg">
            <img width="100%" src="/img/2.jpg">
            <img width="100%" src="/img/3.jpg">
            <img width="100%" src="/img/4.jpg">
            <img width="100%" src="/img/5.jpg">
               <div class="sl_paginationpart">
               <ul id="slidya" class="slpagination">
                  <li><a href="javascript: prevnext(0);" class="prev"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="javascript: thisisit(0)" class="number select">1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="javascript: thisisit(1)" class="number ">2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="javascript: thisisit(2)" class="number ">3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="javascript: thisisit(3)" class="number ">4</a></li>
                  <li><a href="javascript: thisisit(4)" class="number ">5</a></li>
                  <li><a href="javascript: prevnext(1);" class="next"></a></li>
               </ul>             
               </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* ------------------------ START Slider FEATURES ---------------------------- */


.fl{ float:left;}

.slidepart{ width:100%; height:320px; overflow:hidden; position:relative;}
.slidepart img{position:absolute; width:100% }
.slidepart p{position:absolute;height: 100%; opacity: .5%;  }
.sl_paginationpart{ background:url(/../img/slide_paginationbg.png) no-repeat left; width:auto; height:15px; display:block; position:absolute; right:0%; top:5%; padding:6px;}

ul.slpagination{ margin:0px; padding:0px; list-style:none; font-family:arial; }
ul.slpagination li{ margin:0px; padding:0px; list-style:none; float:left; }
ul.slpagination li a.prev{background:url(/../img/sl_prev.png) no-repeat; width:14px; height:15px; display:block; margin-top: 2px;}
ul.slpagination li a.next{background:url(/../img/sl_next.png) no-repeat; width:14px; height:15px; display:block; margin-top: 2px; }
ul.slpagination li a.number{background:url(/../img/sl_nobg.png) no-repeat; width:18px; height:18px ; display:block; text-align:center; margin:0px 3px; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; text-indent: -1px; }
ul.slpagination li a.select{background:url(/../img/select_sl.png) no-repeat;color:#fff; }


/* ------------------------ END Slider FEATURES ---------------------------- */
```

THE JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var slo=null;
    var sola = Array();
    var prev = 0;
    var cur = 1;
    var timi=null

    $(document).ready(function() {
        sol = document.getElementById('slidy').getElementsByTagName('img')
        var sho = document.getElementById('slidya').getElementsByTagName('a');

        for(var i=1;i<sho.length-1;i++)sola.push(sho[i]);

        for(var i=1;i<sol.length;i++)sol[i].style.display = 'none';

        for(var i=1;i<solb.length;i++)solb[i].style.display = 'none';


        timi = window.setInterval('doslide()',3000);
    })
    function doslide()
        {
            $(sol[prev]).fadeOut(500);
            $(sol[cur]).fadeIn(1000);
            sola[prev].className = 'number'
            sola[cur].className = 'number select'

            prev = cur++;
            if(cur>sol.length-1)
            {
                cur=0;
                prev= sol.length-1;
            }
        }
        function prevnext(mode)
        {
            window.clearInterval(timi);timi=null;

            if(mode)
            {
                if(cur>sol.length-1)
                {
                    cur=0;
                    prev= sol.length-1;
                }
                doslide();      
            }
            else
            {
                cur--;
                prev--;

                if(prev<0)
                {
                    cur=0;
                    prev= sol.length-1;
                }
                if(cur<0)
                {
                    cur=sol.length-1;
                    prev=cur-1 ;        
                }

                $(sol[cur]).fadeOut(500);
                $(sol[prev]).fadeIn(500);
                sola[cur].className = 'number'
                sola[prev].className = 'number select' 
            }
            timi = window.setInterval('doslide()',2000)
        }
        function thisisit(aiyo)
        {
            cur = aiyo
            window.clearInterval(timi);timi=null;

            $(sol[cur]).fadeIn(500);
            $(sol[prev]).fadeOut(1000);
            sola[cur].className = 'number select'
            sola[prev].className = 'number'

            prev=cur
            ++cur;
            if(prev<0)prev = sol.length-1;
            timi = window.setInterval('doslide()',2000)     
        }
</script>
```

Comment: @elclanrs We think so much alike that I'm scared.

Comment: also factor in the bad taste of mixing jQuery and non-jquery code

Answer (score 0):

Simply switch:

sol = document.getElementById('slidy').getElementsByTagName('img')

sol = $(".slide")

Then wrap your image with a div with class name .slide...
Then you may add all the content you need

geez guys (elclanrs, Sam Tyson, Ohgodwhy)  thanks, This was someone elses script that I was helping with and I knew there was an easy fix but had a brain fart; oh well, please be nicer with your comments next time, this is a help forum not an expert forum.